# Four Vertex Theorem

Tags: differential-geometry

In Do Carmo's "Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces" he has a proof of the four vertex theorem that I am having trouble getting my head around. In it, he starts by assuming a closed, simple, convex curve is cut by a line passing through the points $p$ and $q$  on the curve where $k^\prime(s)=0$, where k(s) is the curvature. He says that the line splits the curve into two arcs that lie on each side of the line ($L$), otherwise the line would meet the curve in a point $r$ distinct from $p$ and $q.$ He says that by convexity, the tangent line must meet the intermediate point (say it is $p$) and agree with the line $L.$ I don't understand why the tangent must agree with the line at this point. Next, he says that by convexity, this implies the line $L$ is tangent to the curve at all three points, $p$, $q$, and $r$. Again, I cant see why this is true, especially from the diagram he has on the left of page 40 (Figure 1-29, it doesn't seem to depict the same thing as the other diagram on the same page, it looks tangent in one diagram but not in the other.) Continuing on with the proof, I can't understand it and I'm hoping it is due to my misunderstanding of the above. Please try to answer the above question, and if anyone also knows a proof of the four vertex theorem that I may be able to comprehend, please let me know. Apologies for not being able to provide the diagram, I would make it in Tex if I could!

Comment: The proof in question starts on page 36 on this site, http://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/~aar/papers/docarmo.pdf. I also don't see how the Lemma labled (5) is able to be used on the line, as I thought it was ony true for closed, convex curves.

Answer (score 0):

Figure 1-29 (b) depicts why the tangent at $p$ has to coincide with line $L$. Convexity in a loose sense means the curve is always on one side of the tangent at each point. Now note that in fig 1-29(b), if you say that tangent does not coincide with L then it will make some angle with the tangent, hence it will something like the transverse line shown at $p$, but then it will meet the curve elsewhere, and in that case parts the curve will occupy two sides of the tangent at $p$ which is against strict violation of convexity condition.

I think you are clever enough to pick up the rest on your own !

Comment: But isn't the curve depicted in figure 1-29 (b) not a convex curve? It seems to not be convex at points roughly halfway between r, p, and q.

Comment: Also, if p was on the diameter of a circle, and the diameter was line L, the tangent at p would not coincide with L. And a circle is convex, so what am I misunderstanding?

Comment: @lander : For (1st comment) Yes it is non-convex. I think the purpose of the proof is to arrive at a contradiction by refuting convexity which is a basic assumption. 

(2nd comment) : The L for which it happens has to pass through three points r, p, q in order. Actually what you are saying is the fact that is being proved for curve 'C' that if it is convex L will divide it into two arcs on either side no third point 'r' is involved. Assuming that the claim of L does not divide it that way a new point 'r' is born which ultimately contradicts the convexity.